# WPF - Binding and showing a list of Enums and binding back to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Basically, I have an EF entity Product that has a IList<ColorOptions>, and ColorOptions only property is an enum, public Colors color { get;set; }

Each CRUD screen in the app takes in a Product, and the user must select from checkboxes what colors it supports. Options may be Red, Blue, Green, and Other. If they select Other, a textbox appears next to it and they can type it in. I have it working now, but I feel like there's a better, faster way, that could require less code.

Right now each ViewModel has a property for each enum value that can be set, and in the View I'm manually coding however many checkboxes it needs to cover all the enums. So for a Product with the list of color options there would be 4 checkboxes, 1 textbox, and the VM would have 4 properties to support the adding/removing/saving of the color options. I'm generalizing my example, in actuality there are many different CRUD screens for different types of EF entities, but all have a list of enums, and the number of values in an enum may be 4, or it could have 20. Obviously the 20 values enum gets to be a lot of code.

Is there a way to do this in XAML directly? Have a listbox or something that binds to an Enum with N number of values, displays N number of checkboxes plus a textbox if it's an Other option, and when the user selects any of the options it updates the database adding or removing whether or not the user has selected that option?

Like I said, I have it working, but it seems like there's a better solution than having to code N number of checkboxes on a view, with N number of properties in the VM that just take the value and adds or removes it from the DB.

Thanks!

Edit: Just a note, the user can go back in and edit the product in the future so it should display all the options every time they go to this screen, not just the ones they've selected.